# How to display a stdClass type object such result of SQL Sum() statement in a Laravel view?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-8

In the /routes/web.php route file I have the following code:

```
Route::get('/db', function () {
  $result = DB::select('SELECT SUM(votes) FROM table WHERE column1 = ? AND column2 = ? AND column3 LIKE ?', ['US', 3, '30%']);

  return view('read', ['result' => $result);
```

I'd like to know how I could display this result in the view. I though something like

```
{{ $result->SUM(votes)) }}
```

would work, but it's not the case. I received the following error message:

> Call to a member function SUM() on array (View:
> /var/www/tse/resources/views/read.blade.php)

In the /resources/views/read.blade.php view file I printed/dumped the variable like the following:

```
<ul>
  <li> {{ print_r ($result); }} </li>
  <li> {{ var_dump ($result); }} </li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li> {{ $result->SUM(votes) }} </li>
</ul>
```

and received information as follow:

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [SUM(votes)] => 86820 ) ) 1
array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#291 (1) { ["SUM(votes)"]=> string(5) "86820" } }
```

So the query is working well (also direct in MySQL), but I'm unable to display the final plain result 86820 inside the unordered list.

Comment: Use an alias in SQL, `SELECT SUM(votes) as votes_agg` then use `votes_agg` is simplest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give a simpler alias column name to work with like below:

```
$result = DB::select('SELECT SUM(votes) as vote_sum FROM table WHERE column1 = ? AND column2 = ? AND column3 LIKE ?', ['US', 3, '30%']);
```

Then display in your view blade file like below:

```
<li> {{ $result[0]->vote_sum }} </li>
```

Comment: Did the modification, but now I receive following message:

Trying to get property 'vote_sum' of non-object (View: /var/www/html/resources/views/read.blade.php)

Comment: @AloysiadeArgenteuil What does `var_dump($result)` give you? Your post showed it was an object

Comment: print_r gives: Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [vote_sum] => 86820 ) ) 1

var_dump gives: array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#291 (1) { ["vote_sum"]=> string(5) "86820" } }. It's an object I think too. Very strange...

Comment: @AloysiadeArgenteuil It's actually not that strange. It's an array with the first index in it having an object. I updated my answer. I overlooked that initially, but it should work now.

Comment: It works like a charm. Thanks!